# Set format for kendo NumericTextBoxFor

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

Simple question I can't seem to find or figure out with answers I have seen.

How can I get the numerictextbox to only display the number as it comes from the database.

The NumericTextBoxFor at the moment adds two zeros to the returned value.

DB object values:

[image: Db]

Display:

[image: Display]

TextBox:

```
@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.VAL)
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textboxC reset", id = "LeftVA" })
```

I have tried:

```
Format("0:#")
Format("0:n0")
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried this one: `@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.VAL).Decimals(0).Format("#").HtmlAttributes(...)`?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it returns like this then `9900`.

Comment: How about `Decimals(2)` and `Format("#")`? From the table value sounds like the data represented in 2 decimal places but you want to show them without decimal separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have tried those and it still does not work, maybe check your program/web site's culture. If it does not exist, add one to your project for example a culture looks like this

```
Culture("en-ZA");
```